# Upload multiple images from different input type files in laravel

Tags: laravel, image, file, upload

I have 4 input type file with different name.How can i upload 4 images into the public folder and into 4 different column in database in same time?

```
$files=[];
if($request->hasfile('image_front_before')) $files[] = $request->file('image_front_before');
if($request->hasfile('image_back_before'))$files[] = $request->file('image_back_before');
if($request->hasfile('image_left_before'))$files[] = $request->file('image_left_before');
if($request->hasfile('image_right_before'))$files[] = $request->file('image_right_before');
```

if i dd(files); it will show below..It will appear the images that i have upload

```
array:4 [▼
0 => UploadedFile {#441 ▶}
1 => UploadedFile {#445 ▶}
2 => UploadedFile {#439 ▶}
3 => UploadedFile {#442 ▶}
]
```

I think the problem is here..

```
foreach ($files as $file)
 {    
 if(!empty($file))
  {
  $filename= md5(time()).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $path = app(GlobalBookingController::class)- >getBookingImageDirectory();
  $location = public_path($path.$filename);
  Image::make($file)->save($location);
  $data[]=$filename;

 }  

 }
```

Below is the code to insert images into database

```
 $vehicle_image =BookingVehicleImage::updateOrCreate(
      [
       'booking_id'     => $id
     ],
 [
    'image_front_before'     =>$data[0],
    'image_back_before'      =>$data[1],
     'image_left_before'      =>$data[2],
     'image_right_before'     =>$data[3]          
 ]
    );
```

if i upload 4 images in the same time only 2 will be upload into into public folder ..Sometimes for column **image_left_before** and **image_right_before** the images is correct..but for the column **image_front_before** will contain  **image_left_before** and **image_back_before** will contain  **image_right_before**..Sometimes only one column has right images and the other column has 3 same images even upload the different images at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
      'image1' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
'image2' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
'image3' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
'image4' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $article = new Article();

    if ($request->hasFile('image1')) {
        $image = $request->file('image1');
        $name = str_slug($request->title).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/articles');
        $imagePath = $destinationPath. "/".  $name;
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
        $article->image1 = $name;
      }
if ($request->hasFile('image2')) {
        $image = $request->file('image1');
        $name = str_slug($request->title).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/articles');
        $imagePath = $destinationPath. "/".  $name;
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
        $article->image2 = $name;
      }
if ($request->hasFile('image3')) {
        $image = $request->file('image3');
        $name = str_slug($request->title).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/articles');
        $imagePath = $destinationPath. "/".  $name;
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
        $article->image3 = $name;
      }
if ($request->hasFile('image4')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $name = str_slug($request->title).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/articles');
        $imagePath = $destinationPath. "/".  $name;
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
        $article->image4 = $name;
      }

      $article->title = $request->get('title');
      $article->category_id = $request->get('category_id');
      // $article->image = str_slug($request->get('image'));
      $article->subtitle = $request->get('subtitle');
      $article->description = $request->get('description');

      $article->save();
      return back()->with('success', 'Your article has been added successfully. Please wait for the admin to approve.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is for saving multiple images to the particular path and to database

```
$i = 0;    
foreach ($files as $file)
{    
  if(!empty($file))
 {
   $fileName = time().$i++.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
   Image::make($file)->save(public_path('/img/'.$fileName)); //This line will save your image to the particular path
   array_push($files,$fileName);
   $obj->image = $fileName;
   $obj->save(); //save data to database 
 } 
}
```

Comment: does it save the multiple images to only one column that is  image column in database?

Comment: yes, it will save multiple images in one column but in different rows of the database.While saving multiple images you have to use one to many relationship